# Delegated custom events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, this

I have the following snippet:

```
this.el.on('mousedown.' + this.id, '.textcomplete-item', $.proxy(this._onClick, this));
```

What's the pure js (vanilla) equivalent of that? So far I've attempted the following but it doesn't translate:

```
this.el.addEventListener('mousedown.' + this.id, function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.matches('.textcomplete-item'))
        this._onClick.bind(this); 
});
```

Is the callback using `this` in the right context?

Comment: Is `this.el` a jQuery instance? If so, pure JS does not have any way to "classify" event names.

Comment: You have to `.bind(this)` the function expression that you pass to `addEventListener(…)`, and then *call* `this._onClick(e);` inside there.

Comment: this.el is is a ul DOM element, it was instantiated as: el = document.createElement('ul')

Comment: I mean in the first snippet. DOM elements don't have an `on` method

Answer (score 1):

The names for DOM events are fixed. There is no `mousedown.123`, there is only `mousedown`. Also, if you just want to test for a local class, rather than needing to test a full query selector match, you can check the `classList` isntead.

```js
element.addEventListener(`mousedown`, ({ target }) => {
  if (target && target.classList.contains(`textcomplete-item`) {
    element.onClick();
  }
});
```

However, you almost certainly don't want `mousedown` because now you have to also add code for `touchstart`, and you're going to have to make your element focussable so that people with keyboard-only (by choice or by disability) can get to your element, and then you need a `keydown`, and things get just plain ridiculou.

Make your element a `<button>`, style it with CSS to look like whatever you need it to look like, and add a single `click` event listener.